# jQuery Isotope filter by range

Tags: jquery, filter, range, jquery-isotope

### Introduction

Hi, I am using jQuery Isotope to mock-up an e-commerce template for further use.

Isotope is simple but they have not outlined how one creates a filter for custom ranges for certain data.

For example, I may want to filter the products based on the price range so products priced from 100-200 become one filter, products priced from 200-300 become another and so forth.

Basically I want to have multiple filters for price and define the specific values each filter can have.

How can I accomplish this?

### Code Examples

I am using the standard JS code as is written in the isotope documentation:

```
    var $container = $('#list');

   $container.isotope({
     itemSelector : '#list li',
     masonry : {
              columnWidth : 1
            },
     getSortData : {
          price : function( $elem ) {
         return parseInt( $elem.find('.price').text(), 10 );
       },
     }
```

etc...

The html is basically

```
 <ul id="list">

   <li class=="item">
     <span class="price">555</price>
   </li>

    <li class=="item">
     <span class="price">222</price>
   </li>

 </ul>
```

etc..

Answer (score -1):

You can do this quite nicely by [looking here at **user hdias' first comment**](https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues/144) if you scroll down a bit. Basically, you need a simple conditional for your price range and then pass a jQuery object to the filter option.

Comment: So, did the answer lead you to the desired solution?